# java.sql.date , java.sql.timestamp predicate -> Oracle partition data type

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, database-partitioning

Hi we had big Oracle column object and we had partitioned it with a **Data Type** of **DATE**

One of the partitions looks like this :

```
GCP_P1  TO_DATE(' 2011-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') 83  M_DATA01    DISABLED    348132  15214   146 08.06.2014 02:20:40 1078    0
```

Each partition is one week long.

We run our sql's through thin client with jdbc. No ORM just pure jdbc.

When our predicate item for the partitioned column is java.sql.timestamp we realized that the query does not benefit from partition. However when it is of type java.sql.date the execution plan shows a successful partition access.

So for example our sql looks like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ATABLE WHERE PARTITIONED_COLUMN > ?
```

When our java statement is  :

```
preparedStatement.setDate(...); // it benefits from partition
```

But when it is like this :

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(...); //it does not benefits from partition
```

I am looking them from Toad. I have experienced that when it is java.sql.date, It is interpreted as DATE on oracle, when it is java.sql.timestamp it is interpreted as TIMESTAMP

I am following the captured jdbc date type with the following sql statement

```
SELECT *
  FROM V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE
WHERE WAS_CAPTURED = 'YES' AND LAST_CAPTURED BETWEEN SYSDATE-1/50 AND SYSDATE
ORDER BY LAST_CAPTURED DESC;
```

My question is have you experienced such an issue? If so would you direct me to some documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case you describe is documented section 8 - Mapping SQL and Java Types of ["Getting Started with the JDBC API"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/GettingStartedTOC.fm.html)

[**8.3.12 DATE, TIME, and TIMESTAMP**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html)

> Because the standard Java class java.util.Date does not match any of
>   these three JDBC date/time types exactly (it includes both DATE and
>   TIME information but has no nanoseconds), JDBC defines three
>   subclasses of java.util.Date to correspond to the SQL types. They are:

java.sql.Date

> for SQL DATE information. The hour, minute, second, and
>   millisecond fields of the java.util.Date base class should be set to
>   zero. If the number of milliseconds supplied to the java.sql.Date
>   constructor is negative, the driver will compute the date as the
>   number of milliseconds before January 1, 1970. Otherwise, the date is
>   computed as the specified number of milliseconds after January 1,
>   1970.

java.sql.Time

> for SQL TIME information. The year, month, and day
>   fields of the java.util.Date base class are set to 1970, January, and
>   1. This is the "zero" date in the Java epoch.

java.sql.Timestamp

> for SQL TIMESTAMP information. This class extends java.util.Date by adding
>   a nanoseconds field.

Comment: While that is good information on jdbc types, it does not help with the specifics of Oracle's DATE type and how it gets mapped to jdbc types.

Comment: The logic of mapping was presented. There is no requirement to write about how as this is implementation details an may vary. To using the specifics of Oracle DATE type you should go out of the Java API and work with `oracle.sql` package. IMHO that's not the case here as this is done internally in driver.

Comment: It is almost certainly the problem here that the column being worked with is an Oracle DATE type. By using the standard jdbc setTimestamp method, oracle does casting under the covers. To get the desired behavior (being able to utilize an index or partition), one must deal with the oracle.sql.DATE ojdbc object.

Comment: You have right. But that is specified by mapping. If you use `java.sql.Date` will be used DATE, from other hand when you use `java.sql.Timestamp` will be used `TIMESTAP` but In case when you use setTimestamp on `DATE` column. JDBC creates on instance of `oracle.sql.Timestap` and pass it. Because the `TIMESTAMP` is 4 bytes wider (for nanoseconds). During preparation of execution plan engine can not find an index for type `TIMESTAP` therefor it will not use it. This mean that the decision is on db level not jdbc.

Comment: Concluding user should assure that invoke valid method from API, the correctness is based on posted mapping. An alternative way is to pass the arguments directly to statement as you have described in your answer. But we still must know that type is in DB, if we use `oracle.sql.DATE` we will success but if we use `oracle.sql.TIMESTAP` we will fail in the same way OP has.

Answer (score 1):

The oracle [jdbc developers guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28905) contains the mapping from jdbc types to oracle data types. There is a [section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28919) specific to the DATE data type due to its complexity. It has the following note:

> In Oracle Database 11g, if you have an index on a DATE column to be
>   used by a SQL query, then to obtain faster and accurate results, you
>   must use the setObject method in the following way:

```
 Date d = parseIsoDate(val); 
 Timestamp t = new Timestamp(d.getTime());
 stmt.setObject(pos, new oracle.sql.DATE(t,(Calendar)UTC_CAL.clone()));
```